# Designing static Logger with multiple implementations

Tags: c#, logging, design-patterns

Currently there's an API kinda methods exposed to trace the logs for another dependent applications

```
public class Logger {
    public static void Init() {}
    public static void Verbose(string msg) {}
    public static void Warn(string msg) {}
    public static void Error(string msg) {}
}
```

With some design changes, I want to introduce another type of Logger, will be activated based on certain conditions

```
protected class FileLogger {
    public static void Verbose(string msg) {}
    public static void Warn(string msg) {}
    public static void Error(string msg) {}
}

protected class ConsoleLogger {
    public static void Verbose(string msg) { //do diff}
    public static void Warn(string msg) { // do different}
    public static void Error(string msg) {}
}
```

The `Logger` is already exposed and which can be called in static way `Logger.Warn("test")`. What would be the ideal design pattern/implementation to hide the implementation without breaking the contract.

One simple way is to use `if and else` in the main `Logger` to push which one should be called which seems to be pretty vague.

Since it's Logger which didn't expose an `interface` and `with static` methods, what's the `right design to solve the problem?`

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel, I gave an abstracted view. I am not looking for other logging libraries. Mostly query around correct design implementation for such sceanrios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use a static solution, you can simply make the static methods adapters that call a non-static type, which you then inject an implementation of in the Init method:

```
public static class Logger {

    public interface ILog { 
        void Verbose(string msg);
        void Warn(string msg);
        void Error(string msg);
    }

    private static ILog Log {get; set;}

    public static void Init(ILog log) { Log = log; }
    public static void Verbose(string msg) { Log.Verbose(msg); }
    public static void Warn(string msg) { Log.Warn(msg); }
    public static void Error(string msg) { Log.Error(msg); }
}
```

This also makes it easy to inject an implementation of ILog directly into new code, if you want to gradually migrate away from static.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can go with some kind of *functional approach*.

For example:

```
public static class Logger
{
     public static Action<string> Verbose { get; set; }
     public static Action<string> Warn { get; set; }
     public static Action<string> Error { get; set; }
}
```

During application initialization, you might set default delegates to those properties, and the contract won't be broken as the whole `Logger` actions will be called as regular methods:

```
public void Main()
{
    Logger.Verbose = message => 
    {
        // Do stuff here: log text to a file
    };

    Logger.Warn = message => 
    {
        // Do stuff here: log text to a file
    };

    Logger.Error = message => 
    {
        // Do stuff here: log text to a file
    };
}
```

That is, you don't need *implementations as classes* but *implementations as delegates*. You can provide delegates to log to files, to some cloud service or just to the console output...

I guess you're stuck with some legacy code and this is the reason behind requiring a workaround like this.

> With some design changes, I want to introduce another type of Logger, will be activated based on certain conditions

With my proposal you should be able to replace `Action<string>` implementation by storing the delegates somewhere so you can set them to `Logger`:

```
Logger.Verbose = FileLogger.Verbose;
```

BTW I believe that being stuck with a static approach is a bad idea... What if a thread requires a logging implementation while another one requires other? You would end up with some strange solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution can be using [Observer](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Observer/),
Logger is Subject, FileLogger/ConsoleLogger are Observers.

Type of the loggers "will be activated based on certain conditions"(attach/detach observer to the subject).